# How to change permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I want to change `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/` to `/%postname%/`.
How can I do this with `.httacess` or `functions.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Permalink settings are handled in wp-admin under Settings > Permalinks. You can select the "Post name" radio button and save the changes, and your permalinks will be updated.

If this is a live indexed site, you may want to set up redirects for search engines and visitors - that's the only part that would require custom code.